# Understanding MATLAB on multiple cores, multiple processors and MPI

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, mpi

I have several closely related questions about how how MATLAB takes advantage of parallel hardware. They are short, so I thought it would be best to put them in the same post:

- Does MATLAB leverage/benefit from multiple cores when **not** using the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/)?
- Does MATLAB leverage/benefit from multiple processors when **not** using the [PCT](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/)?
- Does MATLAB use [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) when **not** using the [PCT](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/)?
- Does MATLAB use [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) when using the [PCT](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/)?

Comment: To whoever voted for closing the question. Would you mind elaborating on how I can improve the question? Why was it tagged off topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does MATLAB leverage/benefit from multiple cores when not using the
>   Parallel Computing Toolbox?

**Yes.** [Since R2007a](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN), more and more built-in functions have been re-written to be multi-threaded (though multi-threading will only kick in if it's beneficial).

```
Element Wise Functions and Expressions:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Functions that speed up for double arrays > 20k elements 

1) Trigonometric: ACOS(x), ACOSH(x), ASIN(x), ASINH(x), ATAN(x), ATAND(x), ATANH(x), COS(x), COSH(x), SIN(x), SINH(x), TAN(x), TANH(x)

2) Exponential: EXP(x), POW2(x), SQRT(x)

3) Operators: x.^y
For Example: 3*x.^3+2*x.^2+4*x +6, sqrt(tan(x).*sin(x).*3+8);

Functions that speed up for double arrays > 200k elements 

4) Trigonometric: HYPOT(x,y), TAND(x)

5) Complex: ABS(x)

6) Rounding and remainder: UNWRAP(x), CEIL(x), FIX(x), FLOOR(x), MOD(x,N), ROUND(x)

7) Basic and array operations: LOGICAL(X), ISINF(X), ISNAN(X), INT8(X), INT16(X), INT32(X)

Linear Algebra Functions: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Functions that speed up for double arrays > 40k elements (200 square) 


1)Operators: X*Y (Matrix Multiply), X^N (Matrix Power)

2)Reduction Operations : MAX and MIN (Three Input), PROD, SUM

3) Matrix Analysis: DET(X), RCOND(X), HESS(X), EXPM(X)

4) Linear Equations: INV(X), LSCOV(X,x), LINSOLVE(X,Y), A\b (backslash)

5) Matrix Factorizations: LU(X), QR(X) for sparse matrix inputs

6) Other Operations: FFT and IFFT of multiple columns of data, FFTN, IFFTN, SORT, BSXFUN, GAMMA, GAMMALN, ERF,ERFC,ERFCX,ERFINV,ERFCINV, FILTER
```

For code implemented as .m file, multiple cores won't help, though.

Multi-threaded mex-files will benefit as well, of course.

> Does MATLAB use MPI when not using the PCT?

Not to my knowledge.

> Does MATLAB use MPI when using the PCT?

Yes, when you run it on a cluster (though you can use other schedulers as well). To do this, you need a license for the Matlab Distributed Computing Server license. I don't know what architecture the local scheduler uses (the one you use when you run parallel jobs on a local machine); given that MPI functions are part of the PCT suggests that they may use it for at least part of the functionality. 
**EDIT**: See [@Edric's answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016134/understanding-matlab-on-multiple-cores-multiple-processors-and-mpi/8033930#8033930)

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. How do you know that MATLAB uses MPI when using the PCT? Just wondering..

Comment: @intrpc: I don't. I have clarified my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I have accepted your answer. I should note that @Edric clarified this issue further.

Answer (score 5):

To clarify and expand on a couple of points from @Jonas' detailed answer:

- PCT uses a build of MPICH2 (this is not shipped with base MATLAB).
- MPI functions are available under the local scheduler - in this case, the build of MPICH2 can take advantage of shared memory for communication.
- The labSend/labReceive family of functions present a wrapper around MPI_Send/MPI_Recv etc.

Answer (score 4):

When not using the PCT, MatLab issues only one command at once (single-threaded).

However, if you have a multi-threaded BLAS, you could still benefit from extra cores (and it doesn't particularly matter whether they're all in a single processor or not).

MEX files can also be written with multiple threads, in which case you will use multiple cores even without the PCT.  If you have performance problems, rewriting some of the hotspots as MEX is often a big win.

Comment: Some Matlab built-ins have been multithreaded since 2007. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016134/understanding-matlab-on-multiple-cores-multiple-processors-and-mpi/8030177#8030177)

Comment: @Jonas: Those are part of the BLAS, are they not?  Pretty sure that my answer and Iterator's are correct, although some of those libraries do provide parallel operation "out of the box", they're only "built-in" from the perspective of M-files, they're still external libraries not developed by MathWorks.

Comment: Some are part of the BLAS, some are part of other libraries (FFT), some are not part of either, such as `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the answers are mostly "No, but...", as @BenVoigt has addressed.  The "but..." part comes from libraries used by Matlab.  One of the most notable examples was given by Ben, for BLAS, and you can replace this with one that supports multiple cores or processors, such as ATLAS, the Intel or AMD versions, Goto BLAS, or some other options.

You can also call out from Matlab to code in other languages, which can leverage multiple cores, processors, computers, etc.  In the past, I have called R from Matlab, and have made use of multiple cores in this way, by taking advantage of R packages that support multicore processing. The same could be done with MPI.  However, as you scale, you'll discover that more and more of your code ends up being in the language that *can* do more parallel or distributed work (i.e. a free language like R, Python, C, C++, or Java), rather than in Matlab.

So, does Matlab benefit from such infrastructure without PCT?  Not directly.  Can your code in Matlab benefit from such infrastructure via various supporting libraries?  Yes.

Answer (score -1):

When not using PCT, MATLAB uses only one core/one processor.

I don't know the answers to the 3rd and 4th questions.

Comment: Not true, MATLAB has been multi-threaded for many years now. See for example: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/index.html?solution=1-4PG4AN (I believe that information is not updated, so there may well be more)